# Listening to a queue in redis with spring-boot application and lettuce library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lettuce, redisclient

I have developed different services based on Spring-boot, Spring-cloud, and microservices architecture, also I am using the following dependency as `Redis-client`:

```
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.1.5.RELEASE'
```

I have defined my `RedisBean` in Spring as below:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisBean {
    @Bean
    public RedisClient redisClientFactory(AppConfig config) {
        var client =  RedisClient.create(config.getRedis());
        client.setDefaultTimeout(Duration.ZERO);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public StatefulRedisConnection<byte[], byte[]> redisConnectionFactory(RedisClient client) {
        return client.connect(ByteArrayCodec.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCommands<byte[], byte[]> redisCommands(StatefulRedisConnection<byte[], byte[]> connection) {
        return connection.sync();
    }
}
```

I have `SSO` and `ACCOUNTING` services.

In my `SSO` service when a user register, I will push the username in `Queue` like this:

```
@Service
public class AccountingServiceImpl implements AccountingService {

    private final RedisCommands<byte[], byte[]> redis;
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    public AccountingServiceImpl(AppConfig appConfig, RedisCommands<byte[], byte[]> redis) {
        this.redis = redis;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void requestCreateDefaultAccount(String username) {
        redis.rpush(
                appConfig.getCreateAccountQueueName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                , username.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        );
    }
}
```

Now in the `ACCOUNTING` service, I want to regularly listen to the registered `Queue` and whenever a username was pushed, I take it and create a default account for the user.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a suitable solution for my requirements using `io.lettuce:lettuce-core` library.

Any help would be appreciated!!